# Is there a standard way, pattern or idiom to work with bits (for streams, encoding, ...)?

Tags: java, encoding, binary, byte, bit

Recently I saw myself writing a method that would encode characters to bits (doing Huffman, but that's not relevant). Not bytes, but bits; groups of less than 8 bits.

I wrote something like the following, since I don't think there's a smaller unit than a byte. I'm using an array of bytes, and as I put bits into the bytes, sometimes they same group of bits would be in the same byte, sometimes it would be split into to adjacent bytes,...

```
byte[] encoded = new byte[(this.encodedSize/8)+1];
int free = 8;//bits left in the current byte
int byteCounter = 0;
for (int i=0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    char c = input.charAt(i);
    Node n = this.frequencyTable.get(c);
    int v = n.bits;
    if (free >= n.depth) {
        free -= n.depth;
        encoded[byteCounter] = (byte)(encoded[byteCounter] | (v << free));
    } else {
        int overflow = n.depth-free;
        encoded[byteCounter] = (byte)(encoded[byteCounter] | (v >> overflow));
        byteCounter++;
        free = 8 - overflow;
        encoded[byteCounter] = (byte)(encoded[byteCounter] | ((((0x01 << overflow)-1) & v) << free));
    }
}
```

It works, but I found it surprising that I had to write this code myself instead of using something native or provided by some rather core library. As you see, I need to iterate by keeping counters of how many bits I have left in the current byte, or how many bits in the current grouping I will need to add to the next byte. Quite convoluted I would say.

Here I was using java, but I think my question is more generic. This is code that you would need to write for anything that encodes binary into a file, a network stream,...where what your encoding is represented by bit groupings that are not multiples of a byte. As far as I know, most if not all methods that write binary to a file or a socket would do no less than byte units.

My question is, is there a more conventional, possibly built in, way, in java, or any other language, to do this?

I know that java has BitSet to work with individual bits, but that's not going to help for this.